# Detect a finger after TouchDown leaving the control, before TouchUp

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, touch-event, uicontrolevents

I have some `UIButton` instances that execute different code on their `UIControlEventTouchDown` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` events. At the moment I'm hitting an issue where if the user touched down, then dragged their finger out of the `UIButton`'s bounds before touching up, the `TouchUpInside` code isn't run, and as such, the next `TouchDown` causes a crash.

I need a way to error-proof this, so that after a `TouchDown`, the `TouchUpInside` code is executed if the finger is: a) lifted over the button, b) dragged off the button, or c) cancelled in some other way.

a) is solved by `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, and I've tried both `UIControlEventTouchDragExit` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`, but I can't get situations b) or c) solved.

Any idea how I can handle this? Here's my code:

```
[newBall.button addTarget: self action: @selector(buttonDown:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
[newBall.button addTarget: self action: @selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void) buttonDown: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Finger down on button %d!", [sender tag]);

    int senderTag = [sender tag];

    for (CBBall *i in balls) {
        int currentTag = [i.button tag];
        if (currentTag == senderTag) {
            i.body -> f = cpvzero;
            [i replaceDynamicBall: i withStaticOneAtLocation: cpBodyGetPos(i.body)];
            [i setIsBeingTouched: YES];
        }
    }
}

- (void) buttonUp: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Finger up on button %d!", [sender tag]);

    int senderTag = [sender tag];

    for (CBBall *i in balls) {
        int currentTag = [i.button tag];
        if (currentTag == senderTag) {
            [i replaceStaticBall: i withDynamicOneAtLocation: cpBodyGetPos(i.body)];
            [i setIsBeingTouched: NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the target for `UIControlEventAllTouchEvents` and then in the targeted method check the value of `isTracking` property of `UIbutton`
This will solve your problem.

EDIT:

```
if([btn isTracking])
{
    if(flag)
    {
       flag=NO;
       //Your TouchDown Code
    }
}
else
{
   flag=YES;
   //your Touch Cancel and Exit code
}
```

and set flag to YES Before

Comment: But if I do this, how can I differentiate between the Touch Down code, and the Touch Up code? `isTracking` is just a BOOL.

Comment: 'isTracking' gives YES every time except when the touch is cancelled or exited .So you have to set a flag for the first time call of the targeted method

Comment: So, set it to YES the first time it's called, then when can I set it back to NO for subsequent pushes?

Comment: Do something like this 
    if([btn isTracking])
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            flag=NO;
            //Your TouchDown Code
        }
    }
    else
    {
        flag=YES;
        //your Touch Cancel and Exit code
    }
And set flag to YES Somewhere in the start

Comment: This doesn't work, the Touch Cancel code is never called, under any circumstances.

Comment: The issue relates to the bounds of a `DragExit` event – it needs to be 100px away before it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Set the same target to all events you need.

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethodtoHandleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethodtoHandleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethodtoHandleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: This is what I had done. Neither DragOutside or Cancel are working.

Answer (score 0):

For cancel touch you can use UIControlEventTouchCancel .

and for b) , i think UIControlEventTouchDragExit should work , i have tried it and its working , make sure you have properly connected the IBAction.

Comment: I'm not using IBActions, this is all done programmatically, but no, DragExit is not triggering as it should.

Comment: I tried by IBAction and it works , can you show the code you are using for adding action / generating Button?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your points

b) dragged off the button, you need to use `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`

c) cancelled in some other way, you need ot use `UIControlEventTouchCancel`

As such:

```
[newBall.button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:withEvent: )
              forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchCancel | UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
```